ffmpeg долго транскодирует два output'a
Я сочиняю команду ffmpeg, выглядит она следующим образом
ffmpeg -i test.avi -vframes 1 -vf scale=-1:240 -q:v 5 test.jpg -c:v copy -c:a aac -y test.mp4

Она берет avi файл и транскодирует его в test.mp4 и создает preview test.jpg. Все работает, но работает долго. Если делать сначала preview , а затем транскодинг. То работает быстрее. Я подозреваю, что ffmpeg каждый frame проводит через каждый output. Output, который делает preview должен быть обработан только один раз, но он обрабатывает каждый frame. Я пытался найти ключ, но ничего не нашел:(
